# Who exactly killed Luke Skywalker's Aunt and Uncle?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

I know for a fact that there are a few similar questions like mine but none of them are exactly asking what I am.

Now in the first *Star Wars* movie, Luke and Obi-Wan come back to Luke's Aunt and Uncle being a couple of *fried potato chips*.

We know for a fact that they're dead; my question is, do we really know who killed Luke's Aunt and Uncle?

Comment: Non-canonical, but probably the best answer:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zC6QDGTScYQ

Comment: I thought it was implied to be Stormtroopers, but haven’t seen the movie in a while